# Printing extracted emails using PdfLaTeX

Tags: pdftex

My problem is to print emails containing French characters.

I use Gmail and I sometimes get messages in French with French characters which I would like to print. If I print them directly from the browser that works OK but sometimes I would like to edit them before printing. To do that I extract the email to an Emacs text file and after editing and adding the LaTeX preamble I use PdfLaTeX to create a PDF to be printed.

Normally I have `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` in my LaTeX preamble but with this all special French characters are missing in the PDF file. The French characters are OK in the Emacs file

I have found there are other alternatives to `latin1` but all I tried have either caused errors (`utf8` and `T1` are declared as missing) or there are no French characters in the PDF file.

I can of course edit all cedille, circumflex etc. manually but as it is not my text I would prefer not and sometimes the text is quite long.

I understand the text is undergoing several coding transformations on the way from Gmail to PDF but I hope there us some simple way to handle this.

I am using a Windows 10 system, Chrome browser, a fairly recent Emacs and my version of MiKTeX is 2.9.6500.

Testing a little more I realized that there was one option I had not tested and with `\usepackage[uft8]{inputenc}` everything seems to work. I had been confused reading the answers to some related questions recommending to use `[T1]` which does not exist and also `\usepackage[utf8]{fontenc}` which does not exist either.

So I am grateful for the opportunity to ask so I can learn.

Comment: the text  copied from gmail is rather unlikely to be in latin1, are your sure the file is not in UTF-8 ? so `\usepackage [utf8]{inputenc}` (or with modern latex installations omit this altogether as that is the default encoding)

Comment: put one  complete example tex-file somewhere (at best in a zip so that the encoding is unchanged) for inspection.